# How to use cache result

Tags: sql, sql-server, caching

How do you create a cache result that should be used for retrieving and updating data in the cache memory?

The cache result should be used in relation to SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: What cache are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far? There is [memcached](http://memcached.org/), there is [velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx), ORM layers do caching, ASP.Net does caching, there is cache invalidation notifications with [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx), you can add SqlDependency to a LINQ query with [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/) and so on and so forth. It really is a huge topic, you need to be somehow more specific what are your requirements, what have you looked at etc etc.